# JVM ID not found

Tags: java, jvm, websphere

I've recently downloaded and installed WebSphere Application Server 7.0 on Windows 2003.

I wanted to do a jstat (JDK 1.6) to probe the JVM but I kept getting " not found" message.

Any idea why this is happening?

Nicholas

Comment: Can you share the command line you are using and the output you get?

Comment: Hi, I haven't played with this jstat. I was wondering if jstat is supported in a IBM JDK or is something that is supported only in a Sun/Oracle JVM

Answer (score 4):

It can also be because that this flag is enabled in your JVM args

-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem

Either you can remove this from your arguments our disable this flag as

-XX:-PerfDisableSharedMem

Answer (score 0):

[jstat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html) requires a [vmid](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html#vmidentifier) to specify the VM to attach to. Are you providing one?

Comment: yes i did.
in fact i did "tasklist" to the PID (eg 2252)
and then i had this command:
jstat -gcutil 2252 1000

that command is expected to produce some output every 1 second. instead i'm getting 2252 not found

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to monitor a process that is owned by a different user, you can get permission errors.  Work around these by running a jstatd server with a custom, permissive policy.

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/home/root/.jstatd.all.policy
```

.jstatd.all.policy:

```
grant codebase "file:/usr/java/latest/lib/tools.jar" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

You will need to provide the correct path to your own tools.jar.  Once jstatd is up and running, you should be able to run your jstat command.